# biblatex/iso690 (iso-authoryear): related entries (and other fields) missing

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibliographystyle, authoryear

I'm using `biblatex` 3.16 (latest), `biber` (behind the scenes) and the `biblatex-iso690` package (0.4.0, latest) that implements the `iso-authoryear` biblatex style.

I've noticed that various fields, notably references to related entries in the bibliography (`related=`) do not get printed, and I don't know why. Take the following example, which is using the default style:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Keynes1936,
  author      = {John Maynard Keynes},
  date        = {1936},
  title       = {The General Theory of Employment, Interest and Money},
  location    = {London},
  pagetotal   = {403},
  publisher   = {MacMillan},
  related     = {Keynes2018},
  relatedstring = {Repr. as},
}
@Book{Keynes2018,
  author      = {John Maynard Keynes},
  date        = {2018},
  title       = {The General Theory of Employment, Interest and Money},
  isbn        = {978-3-319-70343-5},
  publisher   = {Springer},
  related     = {Keynes1936},
  relatedtype = {reprintof},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This produces

[image]

When changing the style, i.e. using

```latex
\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex}
```

instead, I obtain

[image]

I've taken a look at the documentation for both `biblatex` and `biblatex-iso690`, but haven't found anything that would explain this behavior to me. There is nothing in the `.log` or `.blg` files that would indicate any problem.

FWIW, I'm using MikTeX and xelatex.

**EDIT:** this also affects other fields, such as `volume=` for an entry referring to one volume of a multi-volume book, `language=`, and likely others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A look at the code of `biblatex-iso690` shows that the bibliography drivers don't support the `related` feature.

The drivers in the `biblatex` standard styles end like this

```
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

but those in `iso.bbx` end like

```
  \setunit{\bibpagerefpunct}\newblock
  \usebibmacro{pageref}%
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

I'm not sure why that is the case. I know that `biblatex-iso690` has been around for a long time, so it might have been based on a version of the `biblatex` standard styles that did not have the `related` function. But it could also be that the `related` function was consciously removed, because ISO 690 has nothing to say about something like this.

You can try to get the `related` feature back by copying the relevant code from `standard.bbx` and `authoryear.bbx` and injecting the `related`-block missing from the drivers into `finentry`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=iso-authoryear]{biblatex}

\providetoggle{bbx:related}
\toggletrue{bbx:related}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{bbx:ifmergeddate}{\@secondoftwo}
\renewbibmacro*{date}{%
  \usebibmacro{bbx:ifmergeddate}
    {}
    {\printdate}}%

\newcounter{bbx:relatedcount}
\newcounter{bbx:relatedtotal}

\newbibmacro*{related:init}{%
  \csundef{bbx:relatedloop}}

\newbibmacro*{begrelated}{}
\newbibmacro*{endrelated}{}
\newbibmacro*{begrelatedloop}{}
\newbibmacro*{endrelatedloop}{}


\def\ifrelatedloop{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\xifinlistcs{\strfield{entrykey}}{bbx:relatedloop}}
    or test {\xifinlistcs{\strfield{clonesourcekey}}{bbx:relatedloop}} }}

\newbibmacro*{related}{%
  \ifboolexpr{ test {\iffieldundef{related}} or test {\ifrelatedloop} }
    {}
    {\ifcsundef{begrelateddelim\strfield{relatedtype}}
       {\printunit{\begrelateddelim}}
       {\printunit{\csuse{begrelateddelim\strfield{relatedtype}}}}%
     \usebibmacro{begrelated}%
     \def\bbx@tempa{}%
     \setcounter{bbx:relatedtotal}{0}%
     \def\do##1{%
       \entrydata{##1}{%
         \ifrelatedloop
           {}
           {\stepcounter{bbx:relatedtotal}%
            \gappto{\bbx@tempa}{##1,}}}}%
     \docsvfield{related}%
     \restorefield{related}{\bbx@tempa}%
     \ifnumgreater{\value{bbx:relatedtotal}}{0}
       {\listcsxadd{bbx:relatedloop}{\strfield{entrykey}}%
        \iffieldundef{clonesourcekey}
          {}
          {\listcsxadd{bbx:relatedloop}{\strfield{clonesourcekey}}}%
        \setcounter{bbx:relatedcount}{0}%
        \def\do{%
          \stepcounter{bbx:relatedcount}%
          \ifnumgreater{\value{bbx:relatedcount}}{1}
            {\ifcsundef{relateddelim\strfield{relatedtype}}
              {\printunit{\relateddelim}}
              {\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
               \expandafter\expandafter\printunit
               \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter
               \expandafter\expandafter{%
                 \csuse{relateddelim\strfield{relatedtype}}}}}
            {}}%
        \ifbibmacroundef{related:\strfield{relatedtype}}
          {\appto{\do}{\usebibmacro{related:default}}}
          {\appto{\do}{\usebibmacro*{related:\strfield{relatedtype}}}}%
        \iffieldformatundef{related:\strfield{relatedtype}}
          {\def\bbx@tempa{related}}
          {\def\bbx@tempa{related:\strfield{relatedtype}}}%
        \iffieldformatundef{relatedstring:\strfield{relatedtype}}
          {\def\bbx@tempb{relatedstring:default}}
          {\def\bbx@tempb{relatedstring:\strfield{relatedtype}}}%
        \printtext[\bbx@tempa]{%
          \usebibmacro{begrelatedloop}%
          \iffieldundef{relatedstring}
            {\ifboolexpr{
               test {\ifnumgreater{\value{bbx:relatedtotal}}{1}}
               and
               test {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{relatedtype}s}}
             }
               {\printtext[\bbx@tempb]{%
                  \bibstring[\mkrelatedstringtext]{\thefield{relatedtype}s}}}
               {\iffieldbibstring{relatedtype}
                  {\printtext[\bbx@tempb]{%
                     \bibstring[\mkrelatedstringtext]{\thefield{relatedtype}}}}
                  {}}}
            {\iffieldbibstring{relatedstring}
               {\printtext[\bbx@tempb]{%
                  \bibstring[\mkrelatedstringtext]{\thefield{relatedstring}}}}
               {\printfield[\bbx@tempb]{relatedstring}}}%
          \docsvfield{related}%
          \usebibmacro{endrelatedloop}}}%
       {}%
     \usebibmacro{endrelated}}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro{finentry}{%
  \newunit\newblock
  \iftoggle{bbx:related}
    {\usebibmacro{related:init}%
     \usebibmacro{related}}
    {}%
  \finentry
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{Keynes1936,
  author      = {John Maynard Keynes},
  date        = {1936},
  title       = {The General Theory of Employment, Interest and Money},
  location    = {London},
  pagetotal   = {403},
  publisher   = {MacMillan},
  related     = {Keynes2018},
  relatedstring = {Repr. as},
}
@Book{Keynes2018,
  author      = {John Maynard Keynes},
  date        = {2018},
  title       = {The General Theory of Employment, Interest and Money},
  isbn        = {978-3-319-70343-5},
  publisher   = {Springer},
  related     = {Keynes1936},
  relatedtype = {reprintof},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: KEYNES, John Maynard, 1936. The General Theory of Employment, Interest and Money. London: MacMillan, 1936. Repr. as The General Theory of Employment, Interest and Money. Springer, 2018. isbn 978-3-319-70343-5. KEYNES, John Maynard, 2018. The General Theory of Employment, Interest and Money. Springer, 2018. isbn 978-3-319-70343-5. Repr. of The General Theory of Employment, Interest and Money. London: MacMillan, 1936.]

Comment: I did not address the other fields mentioned in the question, since there was no accompanying MWE and the answer would be quite different: It could be that ISO 690 does not want these fields. It could be an oversight.

Comment: I think they are oversight in most cases, or rather that these features didn't exist when we created the style.

Comment: Thanks and +1 for the answer and the comment (I'll wait for a while to see if anything else'll answer before accepting). The other fields aren't that important, those are cosmetic issues really, but the lack of support for related entries really bugged me.